# How to translate this angular block of code to react

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have this few blocks of code in angularjs and want to know how to use them in reactjs. I'm not sure what the word 'corrections' is doing here. Is it a word that toggles when not clicked or is this used for something else?

```
$scope.corrections=false;
 $scope.correctionanalysis=function(){
        return $http.post('/api/grammarcheck',{'snippetdesc':$scope.snippetDescription}).then(function(response){
            if(response.status==200){
                $scope.recommendationdata['corrections']=response.data
            }else{
                toaster.pop('danger','An error has occured while updating the snippet. Please try again')
            }
        })
    }
```

I tried to do the same in reactjs but not sure if it's right and if "correction" should be declared in states or not

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recommendationdata=""
    };
  }
correctionanalysis(){
  fetch('/api/grammarcheck', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippetdesc: 'snippetDescription'
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  })
  .then(response=> response.json())
  .then((correction)=>{
    this.setState({
      recommendationdata['corrections']=correction.data
    });
  }, (error)=>{
    console.log(error); 
  })
}
```

Comment: You should expose you angular code with html. Without knowing proper use-case, its difficult to answer.  Check you html file how  `scope.recommendationdata` is used. Its for sure being used in html, thats why its in  ** $scope**. Then try to implement same way,

Comment: I checked and there's no recommendationdata in the html file.

Comment: I think if you share minimal working example of current angular code then can be done something.